# Generate table automatically

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation, vector

I have the following:

```
jj=4; (*it can be any integer number lets take it as 4*)
pow=3; (*known value*)
```

[image: Picture of the code]

i need to generate this part automatically from the above expression which the subscript should have the up to the number jj:
[image: exp]

i tried to use:
[image]

but it did not work because it contain {} at the start and end.
is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not entirely sure, that i got what you want to do but we'll see:
if you have a list of values you want to apply to a function you can use [`Sequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html). If you want to generate this list dynamicly, you'll also want to take a look into [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) (Which i use in a Operatorform `@@`).

at Example:

```
argumentList=Table[{r[i],0,5},{i,1,5}]
g[f,Evaluate[Sequence@@argumentList]]
```

> {{r[1],0,5},{r[2],0,5},{r[3],0,5},{r[4],0,5},{r[5],0,5}}
>
> g[f,{r[1],0,5},{r[2],0,5},{r[3],0,5},{r[4],0,5},{r[5],0,5}]

With your respection functions you want to use for g=Table, f="your defined product".

Here an example of a simple case using this:

```
argumentList=Table[{a[i],0,5},{i,1,2}];
Table[a[1]+a[2],Evaluate[Sequence@@argumentList]]
```

> {{0,1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3,4,5,6},{2,3,4,5,6,7},{3,4,5,6,7,8},{4,5,6,7,8,9},{5,6,7,8,9,10}}

And this is another example with a Product:

```
n=3;
argumentList=Table[{a[i],1,n},{i,1,n}];
Table[Product[a[i],{i,1,n}],Evaluate[Sequence@@argumentList]]
```

> {{{1,2,3},{2,4,6},{3,6,9}},{{2,4,6},{4,8,12},{6,12,18}},{{3,6,9},{6,12,18},{9,18,27}}}